# Laravel Return control to caller and continue working

Tags: laravel, request, guzzle

I have two APIs that should communicate with each other. The first one sends the second files, which must be processed. However the processing time is unknown and may take a while.

A solution I thought of is the following - when the processing is ready, the second API sends a request to the first one with the result.
The problem is that in all that time, the first API's request is waiting for a response, because I haven't returned yet the control, which leads into a deadlock.

My question is how can I return a result to the first API (something like received: true/false) as soon as possible, continue with the processing and send the result (from the processing) in a separate request.

I am using Laravel 5.2 and Guzzle for the requests.

Comment: I've never run into anything like this before myself, but assuming you control both APIs, you could generate a token using the first API and send it along with the request to the second along with a *callback URL*. This token would identify the work to be done. The second API would simply queue up a job to process the data and instantly return a result. You can do this using Laravel's queueing system. When the second API's queue has done the processing, it could then hit the first API's callback URL that was provided, passing along the token, to indicate that the work is complete.

Comment: The first API could then simply do what it needs to do to get the results of the processing.

Comment: Did you mean `Laravel 5.2`?

Comment: I control both APIs, that's right and I have a token, and the second API knows where to hit the first to give it back the result. My problem is how to return a response to the first API's request, so it doesn't wait and continue processing. Can you give me some info about queue system, how it works, is it async or background?

Comment: @thisiskelvin yeah, I have made a mistake..it's 5.2

Comment: @DEnchew Going off what @jonathon said, the second api should return some data to let the first api know that it is processing and come back later. A `202` response code is known for `received data which needs to be processed`. So you could continue on if the first api has received a `202` or success of some kind. See https://httpstatuses.com/202

Comment: I see, but how is it achieved programmatically?

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: @DEnchew The queue system is built into Laravel. If you use a driver such as Redis or even the database driver you can push jobs onto the queue using the `dispatch` function and simply return your response. The queue worker running in the background will pick up your job along with the information you gave it and you can do whatever processing you need there. Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, this is proof of concept and not working code and may require some rework.

From your first api, you should be making a call to the second api telling it to process something.

The second api should then respond once it has *received* the data (not once processed).

### First API

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function callApiTwo(Request $request)
{
    $client = new Client()

    $data = [];


    $res = $client->post('http://apitwoexample.com', [
        'body' =>  json_encode($data)
    ]);

    if ($res->getStatus() !== 203) {
        // error in processing
    }

    $resData = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents());
    $token   = $resData['token'];

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Data is being processed',
        'token'   => $token
    ], 202);
}
```

### Second API

The second api should then receive data (files links, images, data etc) and dispatch a job (as mentioned by @jonathon mentioned).

You then need some sort of identifier for the `process`/`job`/`record`. A `id` or `token` of some sort. This is sent back to the first api in its response.

```
public function executeProcess(Request $request)
{
    // Perform logic 
    $token = str_rand(10);

    Job::dispatch('/job/which/needs/time/to/run', [
        'data'  => $data,
        'token' => $token
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Data is being processed',
        'token'   => $token
    ], 202);
}

public function progressStatus(Request $request)
{
    $model = Model::whereToken($request->token)->first();

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $model->status
    ], 200);
}
```

You'll notice the `progressStatus` method, which i've put as an example to check the progess of a `process`/`job`/`record` by some identifier.

From the first api, this can be fired off within an `artisan` command or a `job` which is re-queued to fire again (after a delay) based on whether the second api has confirmed the process completed.

Let me know if this requires more clarity.

Comment: This is just the thing I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DEnchew Welcome!